# Is there a way to take a screenshot of the user's Windows desktop?

Tags: c#, windows, desktop, screenshot

I want to provide the user with a scaled-down screenshot of their desktop in my application.

**Is there a way to take a screenshot of the current user's Windows desktop?**

I'm writing in C#, but if there's a better solution in another language, I'm open to it.

To clarify, I need a screenshot of the Windows Desktop - that's the wallpaper and icons only; no applications or anything that's got focus.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You're looking for [Graphics.CopyFromScreen](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fw1kt6f9.aspx). Create a new Bitmap of the right size and pass the Bitmap's Graphics object screen coordinates of the region to copy.

There's also [an article](http://csharpnet.blogspot.no/2007/01/snap-it-how-to-take-screen-shot-using.html) describing how to programmatically take snapshots.

**Response to edit**: I misunderstood what you meant by "desktop". If you want to take a picture of the desktop, you'll have to:

1. [Minimize all windows using the Win32API](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/785054/minimizing-all-open-windows-in-c/786506) (send a `MIN_ALL` message) first
2. Take the snapshot
3. Then undo the minimize all (send a `MIN_ALL_UNDO` message).

---

**A better way to do this** would be not to disturb the other windows, but to copy the image directly from the desktop window. [GetDesktopWindow in User32](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms633504(VS.85).aspx) will return a handle to the desktop. Once you have the window handle, get it's device context and copy the image to a new Bitmap.

There's [an excellent example on CodeProject](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/system/snapshot.aspx) of how to copy the image from it. Look for the sample code about getting and creating the device context in the "Capturing the window content" section.

Comment: Can I do that if my application is in focus?  Won't it capture my application window (and others) if they're in front of the desktop?

Comment: I tried `GetDesktopWindow` but it captures windows that are in front of the desktop

Comment: any final solution with full source code sample working about it ?

Answer (score 10):

I get the impression that you are shooting for taking a picture of the actual desktop (with wallpaper and icons), and nothing else.

1) Call ToggleDesktop() in Shell32 using COM
2) Use Graphics.CopyFromScreen to copy the current desktop area
3) Call ToggleDesktop() to restore previous desktop state

Edit: Yes, calling MinimizeAll() is belligerent.

Here's an updated version that I whipped together:

```
    /// <summary>
    /// Minimizes all running applications and captures desktop as image
    /// Note: Requires reference to "Microsoft Shell Controls and Automation"
    /// </summary>
    /// <returns>Image of desktop</returns>
    private Image CaptureDesktopImage() {

        //May want to play around with the delay.
        TimeSpan ToggleDesktopDelay = new TimeSpan(0, 0, 0, 0, 150);

        Shell32.ShellClass ShellReference = null;

        Bitmap WorkingImage = null;
        Graphics WorkingGraphics = null;
        Rectangle TargetArea = Screen.PrimaryScreen.WorkingArea;
        Image ReturnImage = null;

        try
        {

            ShellReference = new Shell32.ShellClass();
            ShellReference.ToggleDesktop();

            System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(ToggleDesktopDelay);

            WorkingImage = new Bitmap(TargetArea.Width,
                TargetArea.Height);

            WorkingGraphics = Graphics.FromImage(WorkingImage);
            WorkingGraphics.CopyFromScreen(TargetArea.X, TargetArea.X, 0, 0, TargetArea.Size);

            System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(ToggleDesktopDelay);
            ShellReference.ToggleDesktop();

            ReturnImage = (Image)WorkingImage.Clone();

        }
        catch
        {
            System.Diagnostics.Debugger.Break();
            //...
        }
        finally
        {
            WorkingGraphics.Dispose();
            WorkingImage.Dispose();
        }

        return ReturnImage;

    }
```

Adjust to taste for multiple monitor scenarios (although it sounds like this should work just fine for your application).

Comment: great answer! Spells out what is needed with out being cut -n- paste.  I wish more SO answers were like this.

Comment: Thanks, that's exactly what I was after.  I'm assuming there's a similar method in Shell32 I can call to restore my application to focus afterwards.

Comment: @Damovisa - it's not just your application that needs to be restored. Randomly minimizing all the applications for a user is not good practice...

Answer (score 2):

You might look at using [GetDesktopWindow](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms633504(VS.85).aspx) through p/invoke, then get the device context and take your snapshot.  There is a very detailed tutorial [here](http://www.dreamincode.net/forums/showtopic34831.htm).  It might be better than perturbing the existing windows.

Answer (score 0):

You can always catch screenshot on windows startup before applications run
or use other desktop by using desktop switching. Take a look here:
http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/7666/Desktop-Switching
Switch to other desktop, take picture and remember you dont need to show it just create it "DESKTOP"

Answer (score -2):

All former answers are completely wrong (**minimizing apps is absurd**)
Simply use SHW api : *one line* of code (the desktop bitmap being cached, the api simply blits it to your HDC...)