# client system clipboard print screen image save in server system

Tags: save, clipboard, printscreen

It is possible the client system clipboard print screen image save in server system using C#. net web application

Comment: was that a question or statement?

Comment: So... you want to take a screenshot of the client's desktop out of the client's clipboard and save it on the server?

Answer (score 1):

If you looking at capturing users screenshot then we have [lot of question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/screenshot) in SO. Here is a [sample in c#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/880878/is-there-a-way-to-take-a-screenshot-of-the-users-windows-desktop) .

Th word server confuses me because you cannot take a screen shot of users desktop from your web application.