# jna getDesktop bringWindowToTop

Tags: java, window, jna

I'm having problems activating desktop window.

I have taken the following approach

1: GetDesktopWindow to retrieve the handle of desktop (This works)
I have tried the following methods to bring desktop window to top, but they did not work.

```
   SetForegroundWindow 
   SwitchToThisWindow
   ShowWindow
   BringWindowToTop
```

Is there something i'm doing wrong? Or is not possible to show desktop with jna?

Answer (score 6):

One way is to do get the taskbar's handle and send it a message to hide all windows, perhaps something like this which has worked for me on Windows 7:

```
import com.sun.jna.Native;
import com.sun.jna.platform.win32.WinDef.HWND;
import com.sun.jna.win32.W32APIOptions;

public class ToggleDesktop3 {
   public interface User32 extends W32APIOptions {
      public static final String SHELL_TRAY_WND = "Shell_TrayWnd";
      public static final int WM_COMMAND = 0x111;
      public static final int MIN_ALL = 0x1a3;
      public static final int MIN_ALL_UNDO = 0x1a0;

      User32 instance = (User32) Native.loadLibrary("user32", User32.class,
            DEFAULT_OPTIONS);

      HWND FindWindow(String winClass, String title);

      long SendMessageA(HWND hWnd, int msg, int num1, int num2);
   }

   public static void main(String[] args) {
      // get the taskbar's window handle
      HWND shellTrayHwnd = User32.instance.FindWindow(User32.SHELL_TRAY_WND,
            null);

      // use it to minimize all windows
      User32.instance.SendMessageA(shellTrayHwnd, User32.WM_COMMAND,
            User32.MIN_ALL, 0);

      // sleep for 3 seconds
      try {
         Thread.sleep(3000);
      } catch (InterruptedException e) {
      }

      // then restore previously minimized windows
      User32.instance.SendMessageA(shellTrayHwnd, User32.WM_COMMAND,
            User32.MIN_ALL_UNDO, 0);
   }
}
```

There looks to be another way to do this via Shell32 library calls (something involving the ToggleDesktop function -- for a C# version, check out this [SO link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/880878/is-there-a-way-to-take-a-screenshot-of-the-users-windows-desktop)), but I've not gotten it to work yet.

Comment: Hi this works fine, but however the desktop does not get focus. is there a way to make it so the desktop comes into focus?

Comment: @paktrick: what do you mean by "gets focus"? I'm not familiar with this property of desktops. And how would you test if the desktop has focus?

Comment: by using getforebackground() and reading the title-bar of the handle retrieved. if text is not returned means the forebackground window is desktop. This is because the desktop does not have title-bar.