# Click on button in another program

Tags: java, sendmessage, user32, findwindow

I want to create a program to control another program like a robot.

I have found a solution for C# with user32.dll, but I need one for Java.

Are there any methods similar to `FindWindow` and `SendMessage` in Java?

Comment: Look into using [JNA](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_Native_Access) for adding this functionality to your Java program.

Comment: For example, please look at [this answer of mine](http://stackoverflow.com/a/6091597/522444) as well as [this one](http://stackoverflow.com/a/7699657/522444).

Comment: For my money though, if I wanted to write a program to drive another one, I'd not use Java but rather would use a much more operating system-specific tool such as AutoIt if this were for the Windows platform.

Comment: Are C,C++ or even python good for this purpose ?

Comment: C, C++ and C# would be better, yes.

Comment: Java was specifically written to be as OS-agnostic as possible, meaning that you have to jump through hoops if you want to write code that needs to get cozy with the OS.

Comment: Have you solved it?