# Hiding fullscreen windows sometimes don't work

Tags: c#, winapi, fullscreen

I want to write a program, which allows me to hide open windows.

To achieve this I use `GetForegroundWindow()` to get and `ShowWindowAsync(hWnd, 0)` to hide it.
This works pretty good on most windows, but there are some problems with fullscreen applictions.
For example the VLC Media Player only gets partly hidden: The Fullscreen window its gone, but the original window stays visible. Or the League of Legends Client gets never hidden.

I already tried to solve this by trying to get the fullscreen window by calling `WindowFromPoint(Screen.PrimaryScreen.Bounds.Width/2, Screen.PrimaryScreen.Bounds.Height/2)` if `GetForegroundWindow()` doesn't return a window, but this didn't solved the problem.

Here is the full class:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace HideMyPrograms {

    class Window {

        private bool visible = true;
        private bool wasMax = false;
        private IntPtr window;

        public Window(IntPtr t) {
            this.window = t;
        }

        public int PID {
            get {
                return GetWindowProcessID(window);
            }
        }

        public string Title {
            get {
                return GetActiveApplTitle(window);
            }
        }

        public IntPtr Handle {
            get {
                return window;
            }
        }

        public Image Image {
            get {
                return GetSmallWindowIcon(window);
            }
        }

        public string ProcessName {
            get {
                return GetWindowProcessName(window);
            }
        }

        public string ClassName {
            get {
                return GetWindowClassName(window);
            }
        }

        public Rectangle Rectangle {
            get {
                return GetWindowRectangle(window);
            }
        }

        public bool Visible {
            get {
                return visible;
            }
            set {
                if(value) {
                    if (wasMax) {
                        if (ShowWindowAsync(window, 3)) { //showmax
                            visible = true;
                        }
                    } else {
                        if (ShowWindowAsync(window, 1)) { //shownormal
                            visible = true;
                        }
                    }
                } else {
                    wasMax = IsZoomed(window);
                    if (ShowWindowAsync(window, 0)) { //hide
                        visible = false;
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        public static Window getForegroundWindow() {
            string[] blacklist = new string[] { "Progman", "Shell_TrayWnd", "BaseBar", "SideBar_AppBarWindow", "DV2ControlHost", "Button", "MSTaskListWClass", "SysListView32", "WorkerW" };

            IntPtr window = GetForegroundWindow();
            if (window.Equals(IntPtr.Zero) || IsWindowClassBlacklisted(window, blacklist)) {
                window = GetForegroundWindowByMiddlePoint();
                if (window.Equals(IntPtr.Zero) || IsWindowClassBlacklisted(window, blacklist)) {
                    return null;
                }
            }

            return new Window(window);
        }

        private static Int32 GetWindowProcessID(IntPtr hwnd) {
            Int32 pid;
            GetWindowThreadProcessId(hwnd, out pid);
            return pid;
        }

        private static string GetActiveApplTitle(IntPtr hwnd) {
            const int nChars = 256;
            StringBuilder Buff = new StringBuilder(nChars);

            if (GetWindowText(hwnd, Buff, nChars) > 0) {
                return Buff.ToString();
            }
            return null;
        }

        private static Image GetSmallWindowIcon(IntPtr hWnd) {
            try {
                IntPtr hIcon = default(IntPtr);

                hIcon = SendMessage(hWnd, 0x007f, new IntPtr(2), IntPtr.Zero);

                if (hIcon != IntPtr.Zero) {
                    return new Bitmap(Icon.FromHandle(hIcon).ToBitmap(), 16, 16);
                } else {
                    return new Bitmap(Icon.ExtractAssociatedIcon(Process.GetProcessById(GetWindowProcessID(hWnd)).MainModule.FileName).ToBitmap(), 16, 16); ;
                }
            } catch (Exception) {
                return null;
            }
        }

        private static string GetWindowProcessName(IntPtr hWnd) {
            return Process.GetProcessById(GetWindowProcessID(hWnd)).ProcessName;
        }

        private static bool IsWindowProcessBlacklisted(IntPtr hWnd, string[] blacklist) {
            string name = GetWindowProcessName(hWnd);

            foreach(string s in blacklist){
                if (name.Equals(s)) {
                    return true;
                }
            }

            return false;
        }

        private static string GetWindowClassName(IntPtr hWnd) {
            StringBuilder ClassName = new StringBuilder(256);
            GetClassName(hWnd, ClassName, ClassName.Capacity);
            return ClassName.ToString();
        }

        private static bool IsWindowClassBlacklisted(IntPtr hWnd, string[] blacklist) {
            string name = GetWindowClassName(hWnd);

            foreach (string s in blacklist) {
                if (name.Equals(s)) {
                    return true;
                }
            }

            return false;
        }

        private static Rectangle GetWindowRectangle(IntPtr hWnd) {
            RECT rect = new RECT();
            GetWindowRect(hWnd, out rect);
            return new Rectangle(rect.Left, rect.Top, rect.Right - rect.Left, rect.Bottom - rect.Top);
        }

        private static IntPtr GetForegroundWindowByMiddlePoint() {
            return WindowFromPoint(Screen.PrimaryScreen.Bounds.Width/2, Screen.PrimaryScreen.Bounds.Height/2);
        }

        [DllImport("user32.dll")]
        static extern IntPtr SendMessage(IntPtr hWnd, uint Msg, IntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam);

        [DllImport("user32.dll")]
        static extern IntPtr LoadIcon(IntPtr hInstance, IntPtr lpIconName);

        [DllImport("user32.dll")]
        private static extern int GetWindowText(IntPtr hWnd, StringBuilder text, int count);

        [DllImport("user32.dll")]
        private static extern bool ShowWindowAsync(IntPtr hWnd, int nCmdShow);

        [DllImport("user32.dll")]
        private static extern bool SetForegroundWindow(IntPtr hWnd);

        [DllImport("user32.dll")]
        private static extern bool IsIconic(IntPtr hWnd);

        [DllImport("user32.dll")]
        private static extern bool IsZoomed(IntPtr hWnd);

        [DllImport("user32.dll")]
        private static extern IntPtr GetForegroundWindow();

        [DllImport("user32.dll")]
        private static extern IntPtr GetActiveWindow();

        [DllImport("user32.dll")]
        private static extern IntPtr GetWindowThreadProcessId(IntPtr hWnd, out Int32 ProcessId);

        [DllImport("user32.dll")]
        private static extern IntPtr AttachThreadInput(IntPtr idAttach, IntPtr idAttachTo, int fAttach);

        [DllImport("user32.dll")]
        private static extern IntPtr GetParent(IntPtr hWnd);

        [DllImport("user32.dll")]
        private static extern IntPtr GetDesktopWindow();

        [DllImport("user32.dll")]
        static extern int GetClassName(IntPtr hWnd, StringBuilder lpClassName, int nMaxCount);

        [DllImport("user32.dll")]
        static extern bool GetWindowRect(IntPtr hWnd, out RECT lpRect);

        [DllImport("user32.dll")]
        static extern IntPtr WindowFromPoint(int xPoint, int yPoint);

        [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
        public struct RECT {
            public int Left;        // x position of upper-left corner
            public int Top;         // y position of upper-left corner
            public int Right;       // x position of lower-right corner
            public int Bottom;      // y position of lower-right corner
        }
    }

}
```

EDIT: I found the Error with League of Legends. The Problem wasn't my Window class, it was my Hotkey class. It seems that LoL is blocking Hotkey created with RegisterHotkey(). So i swaped to setWindowsHookEx() and now my program is working.

Comment: Is the problem that `GetForegroundWindow` doesn't bring up the LoL client or that `ShowWindow` doesn't hide it?

Comment: In my opinion GetForegroungWindow doesn't get the LoL Clients handle.

Comment: Its really not a matter of opinion.

Comment: Can you debug it? Those windows shouldn't even "fail" to work.

Comment: Duplicate? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/785054/minimizing-all-open-windows-in-c-sharp