# C# showwindow is not working(#32770 (Dialog))

Tags: c#, api, showwindow, chrome-remote-desktop

## 32770  The class for a dialog box.

I connect to the my pc with chrome remote desktop.

img : https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/getfile/1410849

How can I hide it?

```
Process[] Memory = Process.GetProcesses();
        foreach (Process prc in Memory)
        {
            if (prc.ProcessName == "remoting_desktop.exe" || prc.ProcessName == "remoting_desktop")
            {
                ShowWindow(prc.MainWindowHandle, 0);
            }
        }
```

is not working.

Comment: Please read how to post a [mcve]. This will motivate many more ppl to answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure exactly what you're asking but if you're having trouble minimizing a particular window you could try to minimize all of them. 

 
This thread may help: [Minimizing all open windows in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/785054/minimizing-all-open-windows-in-c-sharp)